# Why Extrude Among Normals don't give me same Depth

Tags: extrude

I try Blender 2.83 and 2.90 and I have the same results.

When I extrude face among normals, the 2 faces seems to go on a different depth causing some not even shapes.[image]
[image]
I try to check Offset Even and it doesn't solve the issue.

Would be great to have some help on that one ;)

Comment: you probably need to apply the scale in Object mode (ctrl A)

Comment: That's it ! Thanks mate ! help a lot !